# How to use to_jsonb as row_to_jsonb? Where the details about "how much"?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I was testing some queries at pg9.4 in "JSON mode", and now I am checking if pg9.5 will bring all same JSONB functionality... But there are no `row_to_jsonb()` function (!). (why it is not  [orthogonal instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set) in the basic parameters?)

[The guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)  only says *"the to_jsonb function supplies much the same functionality"*. **Where we can check "how much"?**   There are other *specific JSONB guide* about this details?

---

**((Year 2022 update and pg upgrade))**

The phrase *"supplies much the same functionality"* was removed on the version 13. The [current Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) does not use the phrase neither the word "much".

Now `row_to_json` **is an alias for `to_json`**  except when the optional boolean parameter is `true` — the result will be the inclusion of line feeds like in `jsonb_pretty()`.

Now the functions  `to_jsonb` and `to_json` are orthogonal (!), and  typical use is the same:

```sql
SELECT t.a, t.b, to_jsonb(r) json_info
            -- or to_json(r)
FROM t, LATERAL (SELECT t.c,t.d,t.f) r;

-- or SELECT to_jsonb(r) FROM (SELECT c,d,f FROM t) r;
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can just use `to_jsonb()` instead of `row_to_json()`, example:

```
with the_table(a, b, c) as (
    select 1, 'alfa', '2016-01-01'::date
)
select to_jsonb(t), row_to_json(t)
from the_table t;

                 to_jsonb                 |             row_to_json             
------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
 {"a": 1, "b": "alfa", "c": "2016-01-01"} | {"a":1,"b":"alfa","c":"2016-01-01"}
(1 row)
```

The first has a wider application than the other because of the type of arguments (`anyelement` versus `record`). For example, you can convert a Postgres array to json array using `to_jsonb()`, that cannot be done with `row_to_json()`:

```
select to_jsonb(array['a', 'b', 'c']);

    to_jsonb     
-----------------
 ["a", "b", "c"]
(1 row)
```

In case of the use of two arguments in `row_to_json()` you should additionally use `jsonb_pretty()`:

```
with the_table(a, b, c) as (
    select 1, 'alfa', '2016-01-01'::date
)
select jsonb_pretty(to_jsonb(t)), row_to_json(t, true)
from the_table t;

     jsonb_pretty      |    row_to_json     
-----------------------+--------------------
 {                    +| {"a":1,           +
     "a": 1,          +|  "b":"alfa",      +
     "b": "alfa",     +|  "c":"2016-01-01"}
     "c": "2016-01-01"+| 
 }                     | 
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is the answer! ...  the answer for *"Where we can check 'how much'?"* is  HERE :-)  And the explanatin about *"specific ... this details?"*, is   1.   "anyelement versus record", 2. pretty-output little difference.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `to_jsonb` as a drop-in replacement for `row_to_json`.

```
SELECT to_jsonb(rows) FROM (SELECT * FROM table) rows;
```

Comment: Ops, sorry the up-vote was wrong... The question says indirectly that I know how to use  `to_jsonb`... **The question is:**  "Where we can check "how much"? There are other specific JSONB guide about this details?"

Comment: that would be an indirect answer, but [in the notes section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) there is statement, that row_to_json allows for pretty-printing optional flag, which is kind of pointless with jsonb anyway. otherwise I didn't observe any issues with to_jsonb

Answer (score 1):

you can cast json to jsonb row_to_json(...)::jsonb, not ideal but often does the trick

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the answer for **the question**: *"Where we can check 'how much'? There are other specific JSONB guide about this details?"*.